How to find repeating characters in a string?
I'm trying to find whether any character in a string repeats five or more times in clickhouse cloud. Examples:
'12344444156'
'abcrrrrrggds'

I know the regex that works in general:
.*(.)\1{4,}.*

But clickhouse is using the RE2 engine which does not support backreference. How else can I do this?
I tried:
WITH '12344444156' as str
SELECT str, extract(str, '.*(.)\\1{4,}.*');

Expected output:
12344444156
Got:
SQL Error [427] [07000]: Code: 427. DB::Exception: OptimizedRegularExpression: cannot compile re2: .*(.)\1{4,}.*, error: invalid escape sequence: \1. Look at https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax for reference. Please note that if you specify regex as an SQL string literal, the slashes have to be additionally escaped. For example, to match an opening brace, write '\(' -- the first slash is for SQL and the second one is for regex: While processing '12344444156' AS str, extract(str, '.*(.)\\1{4,}.*'). (CANNOT_COMPILE_REGEXP) (version 24.6.1.4410 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode [uri=https://w2z74jyoma.ap-southeast-2.aws.clickhouse.cloud:8443/default, options={use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false}]@248459710


If you cannot change the regex engine, only explicit alternation can help, i.e. .*(1{5}|2{5}|...and so on...).*

Something like: SELECT str, arrayExists((x -> 5 <= countEqual(splitByString("",str),x)), arrayReduce('groupUniqArray', splitByString("",str))) ? (I just built that by scanning the docs, I've never used the system)

@jhnc thanks for giving it a go. however, if you look at the regex, it's looking for contiguous repetition. yours will find this for example, '12344415644', which is not intended.

then maybe SELECT str, arrayExists((x -> position(str, repeat(x,5)), arrayReduce('groupUniqArray',splitByString("",str))) ? no idea how inefficient it may be

@jhnc thanks. despite being inefficient, this is the best I've got for now. If you post this as an answer, I can accept this.

Vladimir's approach looks much more efficient than mine: O(n) vs O(m*n)

Try this way:
WITH [
  ' 123444156   ff', 
  ' 1234444156  gg', 
  'aaa bb cc ddd',
  'aaa bb cc dddd',
  '111 111',
  '    111     111    '] AS strs
SELECT
    arrayJoin(strs) AS str,
    splitByString('', str) AS char_arr,
    arrayMap((x, index) -> x == char_arr[index - 1] and not match(x, '\W'), char_arr, arrayEnumerate(char_arr)) AS repeat_arr,
    hasSubstr(repeat_arr, [1, 1, 1]) AS is_repeated;

/*
   ┌─str─────────────────┬─char_arr──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─repeat_arr──────────────────────────────┬─is_repeated─┐
1. │  123444156   ff     │ [' ','1','2','3','4','4','4','1','5','6',' ',' ',' ','f','f']                 │ [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]         │           0 │
2. │  1234444156  gg     │ [' ','1','2','3','4','4','4','4','1','5','6',' ',' ','g','g']                 │ [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]         │           1 │
3. │ aaa bb cc ddd       │ ['a','a','a',' ','b','b',' ','c','c',' ','d','d','d']                         │ [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]             │           0 │
4. │ aaa bb cc dddd      │ ['a','a','a',' ','b','b',' ','c','c',' ','d','d','d','d']                     │ [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1]           │           1 │
5. │ 111 111             │ ['1','1','1',' ','1','1','1']                                                 │ [0,1,1,0,0,1,1]                         │           0 │
6. │     111     111     │ [' ',' ',' ',' ','1','1','1',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','1','1','1',' ',' ',' ',' '] │ [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] │           0 │
   └─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
*/

